# Create Github Token using Elixir HTTPoison Library

Tags: elixir

I want to create a Github token in Elixir using HTTPoison library, but i just cant not figure out how to send HTTPoison the parameter.

When using `curl`, it will be something like [this](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#authentication)

```
$ curl -i -u "ColdFreak" -H "X-GitHub-OTP: 123456" -d '{"scopes": ["repo", "user"], "note"
: "getting-started"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

when I use the HTTPoison library, I just cannot figure out how to post it .

```
url = "https://api.github.com/authorizations"
HTTPoison.post!(url, [scopes: ["repo", "user"], note: "getting-started"],  %{"X-GitHub-OTP" => "12345"})
```

then it gave the error something like this

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
            :erlang.iolist_to_binary([{"scopes", ["repo", "user"]}, {"note", "getting-started"}])
  (hackney) src/hackney_client/hackney_request.erl:338: :hackney_request.handle_body/4
  (hackney) src/hackney_client/hackney_request.erl:79: :hackney_request.perform/2
```

Can someone tell me how to do it the right way

HTTPoison's documentation is [here](http://hexdocs.pm/httpoison/HTTPoison.html#post!/4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is with your body HTTPoison expects either a binary or a tuple in the format `{:form, [foo: "bar"]}`:

```
HTTPoison.post!(url, {:form, [scopes: "repo, user", note: "getting-started"]},  %{"X-GitHub-OTP" => "610554"})
```

or

```
HTTPoison.post!(url, "{\"scopes\": \"repo, user\", \"note\": \"getting-started\"}",  %{"X-GitHub-OTP" => "610554"})
```

You can use the [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison) library to generate the JSON above:

```
json = %{scopes: "repo, user", note: "getting-started"} |> Poison.encode!
HTTPoison.post!(url, json, %{"X-GitHub-OTP" => "610554"})
```

Comment: keywork `:form` is necessry, I didn't know that, thank you very much!!!! It works! I'll try `Poison` too, you really saved me a lot of time!!