# How to perform DELETE in Elixir using HTTPoison?

Tags: curl, elixir, http-delete

I want to execute the  command below in Elixir using HTTPoison Library.

```
$ curl -X DELETE -H "expired: 1442395800" -H "signature: ******************" -d '{"api_key":"***************","delete_path":"*******","expired":"****"}' https://cdn.idcfcloud.com/api/v0/caches
{"status":"success","messages":"We accept the cache deleted successfully."}
```

When I check the document how to `DELETE` in `HTTPoison`

```
def delete!(url, headers \\ [], options \\ []),   do: request!(:delete, url, "", headers, options)
```

There are only `url` and `header` needed. So where should I put the request body(the json body in `curl`)?

In Elixir, I tried

```
req_body = "{\"api_key\":\"#{api_key}\",\"delete_path\":\"#{delete_path}\",\"expired\":\"#{expired}\"}"

url = "https://cdn.idcfcloud.com/api/v0/caches"                                                                                           

response = HTTPoison.delete!(url, header, [req_body])
```

But is seems not work. Can someone tell how to do it the right way please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have identified, `HTTPoison.delete!/3` will send a `""` as the post body. There have been questions here before about if a body is valid for a DELETE request - see [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)

You can however bypass this function and call `request!/5` directly:

```
req_body = "{\"api_key\":\"#{api_key}\",\"delete_path\":\"#{delete_path}\",\"expired\":\"#{expired}\"}"

url = "https://cdn.idcfcloud.com/api/v0/caches"                                                                                           

response = HTTPoison.request!(:delete, url, req_body, header)
```

I have answered a different question which gives more information about generating a post body - [Create Github Token using Elixir HTTPoison Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496216/create-github-token-using-elixir-httpoison-library/32496295#32496295)

Comment: I wish the HTTPoison team considered this use case... The Stripe API for example accepts certain flags in delete requests (for example, when you want to cancel a subscription but keep it active until the end of the billing period, you set `at_period_end` to "true"), so you have to use `HTTPoison.request` with the `:delete` parameter to make it work.